# Laravel Notification Send

Tags: laravel

i have make the notification class.when user log in the notification show Welcome.when we send the notification shoe error 
    **Call to a member function routeNotificationFor() on string**
    SurveyNotification code here

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\User;

class WelcomeToDStrokeTennis extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {


    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('MyApp Welcomes You.')
            ->action('Login To MyApp',         'http://dstroketennis.com')
            ->line('Thank you for trusting MyApp!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
        //
        ];
    }
}
```

My Log in controller where we call the notification send

```
 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    Notification::send($request->toArray(), new WelcomeToSurvey($request->toArray()));
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup user

First of all, you need to set up an user (or another Model that extends the `Notification` class, so the notification knows "where to go".
You can do that through your constructor, or by simply using

`$user->notify(new WelcomeToSurvey($request->toArray()));`

You can get the user through your `$request` object, or through the `Auth::user()` method.

### Provide an email

You need to setup an email where the notification should be sent to!

Add in your `User` model something like this:

```
public function routeNotificationForMail()
    {
        return $this->email_address; //You e-mail property here
    }
```

For more information, check out the [corresponding doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#customizing-the-recipient)

Comment: Now this error show 
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Comment: Could you update your code in your question, so I go through it please? @BilalSiddiq